# Azure Mobile Apps and Xamarin Forms: Authenticate with Facebook in the background

Tags: facebook, azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I can successfully authenticate with Xamarin Forms and my Azure Mobile App backend. Upon the first authentication, the user is prompted with the web facebook login, where he has to login and accept the apps permission requests.

Now, after this, everytime the app is started and the user shall login ( my app needs a logged in user ) the user sees a white screen popping up, disappearing, and the login happened. However this is disrupting the ewxperience, can I do this login in the background somehow ? I dont want the user to see the white screen...
Any suggestions ?

This is the log in code :

```
CurrentClient.LoginAsync(currentContext,
                MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook);
```

Comment: LoginAsync returns a user object you can store. Just store that information somewhere and if it is still valid, you don't need to ask for a login again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code leads to the assumption that you are using *Azure Mobile Services*.

The `LoginAsync` Method returns a `MobileServiceUser`, which contains an autentication token. You can just store that token and reuse it on the next start.

```
var user = await CurrentClient.LoginAsync(...);
```

And set it again on the next run:

```
 CurrentClient.CurrentUser = user;
```

You can find a lot of information on handling token expiration on [Chris Risners' Blog](http://chrisrisner.com/CountDownLatchs-and-Android).

Comment: Yes I am using the mobile services SDK , but they renamed the backend to azure mobile apps whatever its confusing :P So you are saying the user is only a token ? And do i get any information on when it expires ?  Thanks alot!

Comment: User is Token plus UserId. You don't get any additional information. So the only way to check for a valid token is to perform a request an listen for a 401. But I think that's a new question to ask. :) Azure Mobile Apps only cover simple Szenarios and if you need full control, you probably need to look for a fully featured authentication like Active Directory.

Comment: Hmm i tried to store the data and add it later on, but it seems like the authentication is not working properly then, my requests do end up in server errors because the user is not authenticated...

Comment: Ok ignore my last comment, its working perfectly now thanks!